# How to create a property of generic class type?

Tags: c#, generics, properties

I have this code:

```
public class SelectionList<T> : ObservableCollection<SelectionItem<T>> where T : IComparable<T>
{
  // Code 
}

public class SelectionItem<T> : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
// Code
}
```

I need to create a property which is of the type `SelectionList` as follows:

```
public SelectionList<string> Sports { get; set; }
```

But when I replace string with DataRowView, as

```
 public SelectionList<DataRowView> Sports { get; set; }`
```

I am getting an error. Why doesn't this work?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your problem is that `string` implements [`IComparable<string>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.icomparable.aspx) and `DataRowView` doesn't.

`SelectionList<T>` has a constraint that `T` must implement `IComparable<T>`, hence the error.

```
public class SelectionList<T> : ObservableCollection<SelectionItem<T>> where T : IComparable<T>
{
  // Code 
}
```

One solution would be to subclass DataRowView and implement `IComparable`:

```
public class MyDataRowView : DataRowView, IComparable<DataRowView>{
  int CompareTo(DataRowView other) {
    //quick and dirty comparison, assume that GetHashCode is properly implemented
    return this.GetHashCode() - (other ? other.GetHashCode() : 0);
  }
}
```

Then `SelectionList<MyDataRowView>` should compile fine.

Comment: Hi, I have the following questions :
1. By "subclass DataRowView", do u mean subclass of SelectionList?
2. Do I have to override GetHashCode ?

Comment: No no, `DataRowView`. `GetHashCode` is only there as a quick hack. `CompareTo` should return an integer value indicating whether or not `this` is less than, equal or greater than `other` as far as sorting order goes.

Comment: Can you answer my first question plz?

Comment: You need to subclass DataRowView, not SelectionList, as it is not a suitable class for SelectedList type constraints.

Answer (score 4):

You have a constraint on your class `where T : IComparable<T>`. DataRowView does not implement `IComparable<DataRowView>` and therefore cannot be used in this case.

See here for more information about Generic Constraints: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d5x73970.aspx